# Compare and delete datatable row using C#:

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, datatable

I have two tables such as DTTable1 and  DTTable2. It has the following records.

DTTable1:

```
    ItemID     Specification    Amount
   ---------  ---------------  ---------
      1             A             10
      1             B             20
      1             C             30
```

DTTable1:

```
    ItemID     Specification    Amount
   ---------  ---------------  ---------
      1             A             10
      1             B             20
      1             C             30
      2             A             10
      2             B             20
      3             A             10
      3             B             20
```

Here I want to compare these two tables. If DTTable1 records present in DTTable2(consider only ItemID) then remove the corresponding rows which has the ItemID same as DTTable1.

I have tried foreach and forloop. 
Using ForEach:

```
   foreach (DataRow DR in DTTable2.Rows)
   {
      if (DR["ItemID"].ToString() == DTTable1.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString())
      {
           DTTable2.Rows.Remove(DR);                            
      }
   }
   DTTable2.AcceptChanges();
```

It showed the error,
       "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute". So I used For Loop, It also not given the desired result.

Using For Loop:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < DTTable2.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       if (DTTable2.Rows[i]["ItemID"].ToString() == DTTable1.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString())
       {
           DTTable2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
       }
   }
   DTTable2.AcceptChanges();
```

But sometimes, the second row doesn't remove from the table. I get the final DataTable as

```
    ItemID     Specification    Amount
   ---------  ---------------  ---------
      1             B             20
      2             A             10
      2             B             20
      3             A             10
      3             B             20
```

How to solve this? What is the simplest method to do this?

Comment: Are you selecting these records from the database, if so, I can help you with the query which will select just the required records as it is far more efficient to get it done with sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify a collection while you are enumerating it as in your first example. You should instead get a list of the rows to delete and then delete them.

```
List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow DR in DTTable2.Rows)
{
    if (DR["ItemID"].ToString() == DTTable1.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString())
        rowsToDelete.Add(DR);           
}

foreach (var r in rowsToDelete)
    DTTable2.Rows.Remove(r);
```

Or, inline using linq:

```
DTTable2.Rows
    .Where(DR => DR["ItemID"].ToString() == DTTable1.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r => DTTable2.Rows.Remove(r));
```

---

Your second example fails because once a row is removed, the indexes of subsequent rows change but you continue to increment `i`, which effectively skips over the row immediately following the deleted row. There are two ways around this:

```
for (int i = DTTable2.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (DTTable2.Rows[i]["ItemID"].ToString() == DTTable1.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString())
        DTTable2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

Or

```
int i = 0;
while (i < DTTable2.Rows.Count)
{
    if (DTTable2.Rows[i]["ItemID"].ToString() == DTTable1.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString())
        DTTable2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    else
        i++;
}
```

---

Side note: I wonder if you really mean to always compare to *row 0's* data, given your description. Perhaps you meant to compare all rows like the following instead (although not optimal at all)?

```
if (DTTable1.Any(r => DTTable2.Rows[i]["ItemID"].ToString() == r["ItemID"].ToString()))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
var list = DTTable2.Rows.ToList();//create new list of rows
foreach (DataRow DR in list)
{
    //if bla bla bla
    DTTable2.Rows.Remove(DR);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use *LINQ to DataTable*:

```
var result =  DTTable1.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(row => !DTTable2.AsEnumerable()
                                         .Select(r => r.Field<int>("ItemID"))
                                         .Any(x => x == row.Field<int>("ItemID"))
                  ).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, guys. I had an almost identical situation and no matter how I tried to do it, I kept running into problems. My solution was not to try and loop through the DataTable at all. I made an array from the first DataTable (this contained the rows that needed to be deleted from the second DataTable). Loop through the Array and use a **select** to remove the row that matched in the DataTable. Since it wasn't a loop, and it could match any row in the DataTable, I quit getting errors.

Note: Original DataTable is a 1-column table that contains what you are trying to remove from the second DataTable by row (doesn't matter how many columns it has). Replace "LinkName=' w/ the column name for your 1-column table.

```
 public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable OriginalLinks, DataTable UpdatedLinks) // OriginalLinks is a 1-col dt to delete from new dt
    {

        ArrayList arrOriginalLinks = new ArrayList();

        if (OriginalLinks.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (DataRow dr in OriginalLinks.Rows)
            {
                arrOriginalLinks.Add(dr["LinkName"]);
            }
        }


        if (OriginalLinks.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = OriginalLinks.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                string filter = "LinkName='" + arrOriginalLinks[i].ToString() + "'";

                UpdatedLinks.Select(filter).ToList().ForEach(r => r.Delete());


            }

        }

        return UpdatedLinks;

    }
```

This returns the second DataTable with just the rows left that didn't match a value found in the first DataTable.